# HTML CSS Уменьшить размер текста в %

Tags: html, css

Допустим есть блок `a` с `font-size: 13px;` затем блок `b` с 12.5px и `c` со 100%. Возможно ли увеличить / уменьшить размер текста в них без прямого редактирования, то есть к примеру прибавить 10% ко всем, чтобы в `a` вышло 13.13px, в блоке `c` 110% и т.д. ? Чтобы вышло на подобии `text-transform: scale(1.1);`

Comment: пожалуйста, уделяйте больше времени оформлению вопроса. Он должен быть удобен для прочтения не только Вам.

Comment: @Alex старый добрый коммьюнити SO. Пользователи дадут советы, вставят свой комментарий об орфографии или по чему-либо другому не по теме, покажут свои знания правил и конечно же ответят на всё кроме вопроса

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Правила придуманы не просто так, нужно думать о тех кто потратит свое личное время для помощи Вам и о тех, кто будет читать Ваш вопрос в дальнейшем если столкнется с подобной проблемой.
P.S.: вероятно у Вас какая-то обида с давних времен на кого-то. Просто подумайте о том, что если Вы будете внимательнее и добрее, то и желания Вам помочь будет больше у большего количества пользователей.

Comment: @Alex нет обиды просто достаточно предложить правку

Comment: если Вам не понравилась правка Вы можете ее изменить или полностью откатить. Предлагать правку могут участники с низкой репутацией, правки, сделанные участниками с репутацией 2k и больше, минуют проверку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте единицы измерения `em`. Почитать можно [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units).

```css
.c1 {
font-size: 13px;
}
.c2 {
font-size: 26px;
}
.v1 {
color: red;
font-size: 1em;
}
.v2 {
color: green;
font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
<span class="v1">Текст 1 к 1</span>
<span class="v2">Текст +30%</span>
</div>

<div class="c2">
<span class="v1">Текст 1 к 1</span>
<span class="v2">Текст +30%</span>
</div>
```

По сути, вы задаете внутренним блокам значения, где `1em` - это размер родителя, а `1.15em` - +15% к размеру родителя. Соответсвенно, изменив размер родителя, все внутренние блоки изменятся тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте em. 1em - 100% , 1.01em это уже 101% , думаю суть понятна. Одна сотая это 1%